# Is $1-10\sqrt{-17}$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-17}]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory

I would like to know how to determine whether $1-10\sqrt{-17}$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-17}]$(Hint: it is)? I tried the norm, which was suggested in similar questions and equals $1701=3^5\times 7$ but this seems way too large to do anything with. I tried also $1-10\sqrt{-17}=(a+b\sqrt{-17})(c+d\sqrt{-17})$, but I get a very nasty number theory problem. I put it into wolfram alpha and there are no nontrivial solutions. But how would I find that out?

Comment: Do you have relations for $a, b, c, d$ in multiplying out the product above, and if so, perhaps they don't hold modulus $1701$?

Comment: One of the factors must have the norm $\leq\sqrt{1701}\approx41$, and there are very few integers $a,b$ with $a^2+17b^2\leq41$.

Comment: @Conifold, actually the upper bound is $27$, which is the largest factor of $1701$ less than $\sqrt{1701}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1-10\sqrt {-17})(1+10\sqrt {-17})=1701=81\times 21$

Let $(a+b\sqrt{-17})(a+b\sqrt{-17})=a^2+17b^2$

For b=1 we have $a^2+17b=21\Rightarrow a=2$

For a=8 we have $8^2+17b^2=81\Rightarrow b=1$

And we can write:

$(2+\sqrt{-17})(8+\sqrt{-17})=16+10\sqrt{-17}-17=-(1-10\sqrt{-17})$